# Editing third party program with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

We have a vb.net program that was created by a third party (outsourced). The project files have no solution files. There is some javascript implemented. I need to edit some of the code and try to figure out the best way to do so. I did create a new project in Visual Studio and just copied all the files over. When I went to build the project, 102 errors followed.

Is there any easy way to edit this project? Or, will I need to correct very error beforehand?

Thanks,

Josh

Comment: Very hard to help without knowing the errors. Also 102 errors is max it will show. Probably a lot more

Comment: Could you provide more info on it? Also, all of them might not be errors. Sometimes, errors prevents further building of the application resulting in additional errors. Not sure if that is the case for you though.

Comment: It may simple as  you having option strict on and the original programmer didn't.  If that is the case I would strongly suggest you fix all of the errors.

Comment: Thanks for all of your responses. I have errors such as SqlDataReader not defined, which is easy enough to correct. Most of the others are as follows: Session not a member of My; '' not a member f 'Util.

Comment: Does a program exist to help with situations like this? I've heard of .Net Reflector, but I have no knowledge on it.